# Can't get Tower (OSX git GUI) to ignore file permissions – "could not lock config file .git/config" error

Tags: macos, git, git-tower

### Issue:

1. Can't get Tower (OSX git App) to ignore file permissions

---

### Set up:

1. OSX 10.9.5
2. Using Tower 2.1.3 set to use git from:

`/usr/bin/git (System; 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)`

---

### Have tried:

- Looking for a file mode setting in Tower / Tower docs
- From Terminal, have tried:

`$ git config core.fileMode false`

- Which outputs:

`error: could not lock config file .git/config: No such file or directory`

- In Terminal, I can't see:

`~/.git/config`

`/.git/config`

`/usr/bin/git`

`/usr/bin/.git`

---

### Question:

Does anyone know how to get Tower on OSX to ignore file permissions?

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git config` would work within a git repo.

Outside a particular git repo, you would type:

```
git config --global core.fileMode false
```

Then check with Tower again (restarting it just to be sure).

The [OP CMSCSS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854987/cmscss) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539571/cant-get-tower-osx-git-gui-to-ignore-file-permissions-could-not-lock-confi/27540451#comment43530077_27540451):

> running `git config core.fileMode false` within the repo's `/.git` directory worked.

Comment: ```$ git config --global core.fileMode false``` didn't work but running ```$ git config core.fileMode false``` within the repo's ```/.git``` directory worked a treat. Cheers

Comment: @CMSCSS Ok, I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.